# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following: <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> LONG_

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

When I try to run the below query I get the following error:

```
ERROR at line 6:
```

ORA-06550: line 6, column 30:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:
  LONG_
double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national
character nchar

```
DECLARE
thisdb int;
maxDB int;
execStatement VARCHAR2 (120);
execStatement2 VARCHAR2 (120);
TYPE databaseIDs IS TABLE OF (EXECUTION_ID RAW (32));


BEGIN
INSERT INTO databaseIDs (EXECUTION_ID)
              SELECT distinct jhist.EXECUTION_ID
                FROM sysman.MGMT_JOB_HISTORY jhist, sysman.MGMT_JOB job
                WHERE jhist.job_id=job.job_id and
                 job.job_owner='admin'
                 and jhist.step_status not in (1,5,17)
                 and start_time > (sysdate -1);

INSERT INTO databaseIDs (EXECUTION_ID)
              SELECT distinct log_ID
                FROM all_scheduler_job_log
                WHERE owner = 'admin' 
              AND status <> 'SUCCEEDED'
                AND log_date > (sysdate -1);


maxDB := select max(EXECUTION_ID) from databaseIDs;
thisdb := select min(EXECUTION_ID) from databaseIDs;

WHILE thisdb <= maxDB 
LOOP
maxDB >= thisdb
END LOOP;



BEGIN
                            execStatement := (Select '
INSERT INTO TEST.JOB_FAILURES
              SELECT distinct jhist.EXECUTION_ID,job_owner,job_name,
                           DECODE(step_status,
                 1, ''SCHEDULED'',
                 2, ''RUNNING'',
                 3, ''FAILED INIT'',
                 4, ''FAILED'',
                 5, ''SUCCEEDED'',
                 6, ''SUSPENDED'',
                 7, ''AGENT DOWN'',
                 8, ''STOPPED'',
                 9, ''SUSPENDED/LOCK'',
                 10, ''SUSPENDED/EVENT'',
                 11, ''SUSPENDED/BLACKOUT'',
                 12, ''STOP PENDING'',
                 13, ''SUSPEND PENDING'',
                 14, ''INACTIVE'',
                 15, ''QUEUED'',
                 16, ''FAILED/RETRIED'',
                 17, ''WAITING'',
                 18, ''SKIPPED'', step_status) AS STATUS,
                 cast(end_time AS timestamp) AS RUNDATE
                FROM sysman.MGMT_JOB_HISTORY jhist, sysman.MGMT_JOB job
                WHERE jhist.job_id=job.job_id and
                 job.job_owner='admin'
                 and jhist.step_status not in (1,5,17)
                 and start_time > (sysdate -1)
                           and jhist.EXECUTION_ID = '' + EXECUTION_ID + ''
WHERE NOT EXISTS (        SELECT distinct jhist.EXECUTION_ID
                FROM sysman.MGMT_JOB_HISTORY jhist, sysman.MGMT_JOB job
                WHERE jhist.job_id=job.job_id and
                 job.job_owner='DBadmin'
                 and jhist.step_status not in (1,5,17)
                 and start_time > (sysdate -1)
                           and jhist.EXECUTION_ID = '' + EXECUTION_ID + '';'from databaseIDs  where EXECUTION_ID = thisdb);
                           --print execStatement
                           exec(execStatement)

                           execStatement2 := (Select '
INSERT INTO TEST.JOB_FAILURES
        SELECT distinct owner,job_name,status, cast(log_date AS timestamp) as column1
                FROM all_scheduler_job_log
                WHERE
                 owner = 'admin' and
                 status <> 'SUCCEEDED'
                 and log_date > (sysdate -1)
                           and log_ID  = '' + EXECUTION_ID + ''
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT distinct log_ID
                FROM all_scheduler_job_log
                WHERE
                 owner = 'admin' and
                 status <> 'SUCCEEDED'
                 and log_date > (sysdate -1)
                           and log_ID = '' + EXECUTION_ID + '';'from databaseIDs  where EXECUTION_ID = thisdb);
                           --print execStatement
                           exec(execStatement2)

        thisdb := (select min(EXECUTION_ID) from databaseIDs  where EXECUTION_ID > thisdb)
END;
/
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Where [in the Oracle manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/toc.htm) did you find that syntax?

Comment: This does not look like Oracle syntax

Comment: Regarding the error message in the title, [user-defined identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS002) must begin with a letter, not `@`. There's also no `set` command and as others have mentioned, statements must be terminated with a semicolon. I think a glance at the manual may be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to run code for SQL Server, or some other RDBMS, in Oracle. The syntaxes are not the same.  For instance, the use of @ to prefix variable names is not part of Oracle PL/SQL syntax.  There are other issues as well, such as that individual commands should be terminated with semicolons.

Comment: I'm able to run parts of the code if I break it down part by part in oracle.

Comment: Not sure what your point is.  Some aspects of syntax are common between multiple database systems.  For instance, pure ANSI SQL statements should run in different systems with no problem.  So it's not surprising that some parts of your code run in Oracle by themselves.  If you think you have an example that contradicts my answer, please share it.

Comment: @Terry Trying to run Microsoft T-SQL code in Oracle is the same thing than trying to run Java code with Python interpreter. T-SQL and PL/SQL are two different vendor specific languages that extend the capabilities of SQL.

Comment: Hey Dave I've updated the code and have gotten a new error would you be able to help?